# What is the best way to store N amount arrays ? C

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

My input should be something like this :

```
n array1 array2 array3 array4 ... arrayn
```

Where n is an integer and array1 .. arrayn are arrays. The arrays always have 4 elements.
I could do something like this :

```
int n,array[100][4];
for(int i=0;i<=n-1;i++)
{   
    for(int j=0;j<=3;j++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&array[i][j]);
    }

}
```

But that is a matrix and I think there are better solutions but I really can't think of any...

Comment: What's wrong with a matrix?

Comment: _Side note:_ Don't you want `scanf("%d",&array[i][j]);`?

Comment: @Barmar I need to learn to save space/memory as much as I can ... I am just looking for other alternatives and my brain refuses to come up with something different .

Comment: @CraigEstey yea sorry,thanks,I will edit it

Comment: Would a VLA help: (e.g.) `int n = 100; int array[n][4];`? Or, if `n` is too large for the stack, doing `int *array = malloc(n * 4 * sizeof(int));` and then doing your own 2D indexing manually (e.g.) `#define ARRAY(y,x) array[((y) * 4) + (x)]` and then use `ARRAY(i,j)`

Comment: Would it be possible to run the operations you need done on each array within a separate function before you read the next array? If you read the array in a different function called in the loop and just execute the function repeatedly for each different array the array will be popped off the stack after each function call. Outside of that, if you need the arrays to persist in memory there isn't much you can do outside of using a matrix. Even if you decided to use a pointer instead and `malloc` or `calloc` the required memory you'd still use up the same amount of memory.

Comment: @Mike Oh I understand,thank you,guess I will stick with this

Comment: It depends a bit on how you'll be accessing the data, but it might be more sensible to use `int array[4][10]` instead of the other way around. That will group the entries for `array2` together, rather than interleaving them with the data for the other arrays.  Both work (if coded appropriately).

Comment: Tip: an important goal [save space/memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45493436/what-is-the-best-way-to-store-n-amount-arrays-c/45494169#comment77948692_45493436) is _missing_ from your post.  In the future be sure to add/append info like this to the post to add clarity.  A comment is insufficient.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the best way to store N amount arrays?
>   The arrays always have 4 elements

Some choices:  What is best depends on unstated coding goals.  Consider option `B` if unsure.  Each uses about the same amount of memory.  VLAs live locally and should be avoid for large `n`.

```
  unsigned n = rand();

  // arrayA as array n of array 4 of int
  // Variable-Length-Array (VLA) available in C99 and optionally in C11
  // UB if n == 0
  int arrayA[n][4];
  arrayA[0][0] = 42;
  // no free() needed.  Become invalid at the end of the block

  // arrayB as pointer to array 4 of int
  // Allocate memory for a n 1D arrays
  int (*arrayB)[4] = malloc(sizeof *arrayB * n);
  if (n > 0) arrayB[0][0] = 42; 
  free(arrayB);  // Valid until free'd

  // arrayC as pointer to array n of array 4 of int
  // Allocate memory for a 2D VLA  (C99,C11 maybe)
  // UB if n == 0
  int (*arrayC)[n][4] = malloc(sizeof *arrayC);
  (*arrayC)[0][0] = 42;
  free(arrayC); // Valid until free'd
```

Return values from `malloc()` should be check for `NULL-ness`

```
  p = malloc(sizeof *p * n);
  if (p == NULL && n > 0) {
    Handle_OutOfMemory();
  }
```